# Fit Webview to Iphone Screen resolution

Tags: ios, uiwebview

How to fit Webview to Iphone and Ipads Resolution

Any help should be Appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: Do you want to set the WebView onto the screen completely?

Comment: yes i want to set it completely

Comment: Edit your question correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this,

```
myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
myWebView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```